# Can't run Qt 5.12.2 on macOS 10.12

Tags: macos, qt, macos-sierra

There is a project I need to build using Qt. I am running macOS 10.12.6 and I have installed XCode 9.2 along with its command line tools. But after installing Qt 5.12.2 (the oldest 5.12 available through its online installer). It will not launch Qt. When I look into the ~/Qt directory, the "Qt Creator" App is showing that it is for macOS 10.13. But Qt's site says 10.12 is supported.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/supported-platforms.html

It has a footnote of:  Note: Xcode 9 is only supported for application development (to be able to opt out of features such as layer-backing and dark mode), not for development of Qt itself.

Am I misunderstanding the requirement? I don't want to upgrade my OS at this points as I don't want to destabilize my other development.

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: You can't use this version of the application "Qt Creator.app" with this version of macOS. You have macOS 10.12.6. The application requires macOS 10.13 or later.  - That's the error

Comment: The installer ships various Qt versions, but only the latest Qt Creator, which is probably too new (4.11.0 is using Qt 5.14). Try an older Qt Creator version (https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qtcreator/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the Qt online installer ships various Qt versions, it only ships the latest Qt Creator, which is currently Qt Creator 4.11.0, based on Qt 5.14.0. Thus it is too new, as Qt 5.14.0 only supports macOS 10.13 and later.

You'll have to install [Qt Creator 4.9.2](https://download.qt.io/archive/qtcreator/4.9/4.9.2/), which is using Qt 5.12.4 (Qt Creator 4.10 might also work, as Qt 5.13 is supposed to still run on macOS 10.12, but I find the documentation a bit unclear - give it a try).

Install the Qt Creator simply to /Applications, to avoid any clashes with the online installer-based Qt installation. You might have to configure the installed Qt versions and kits manually then, as the alternate Qt Creator probably won't auto-detect them.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up skipping the online installer and downloaded the specific Qt version. And it comes with a compatible Qt Creator.

Comment: Good post but link to Qt Creator 4.9.2 does not work, not found.

Comment: @SPlatten I've updated the link